Let $a_n\ge0$. Does $\sum_{n\ge1}\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\dots a_n}$ converge if $\sum_{n\ge1}a_n$ does?
Let $a_n \geq0$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges. Is it true that for every such sequence the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2 \ldots a_n}$ also converges? I couldn't find a counterexample and, at the same time, couldn't prove this. I tried to use AM-GM and apply Dirichlet's convergence test, but that was a bad idea. I also tried the root test, but I failed. I don't know what else I can do to solve this.
